How to set the locale (country) on Samsung Android 14?
I've set English as the default language on my Samsung Galaxy A35 (Android 14) and German (Switzerland) as a second language.
How do I set the locale to CH (Switzerland)?
I need numbers, units, time formatting as it should be in CH but the phone uses US settings (from the default language). The UI does not offer to set English (Switzerland) as a language.
I've read somewhere that Android 14 supports setting the regional details but could not find this setting.
Applications to set the locale do not longer exist or work. Setting the locale using ADB with "setprop persist.sys.locale en-CH" results in an error.
PS: I actually would prefer the date formatting yyyy-mm-dd instead of dd.mm.yyyy common here.

Talking about date format on Android you might find this discussion  helpful: There's an option to make device follow the date format in your region at the bottom of screen [Settings - System - Date & time].
forum discussion
BTW I also did a test and I was able to choose English ->(All regions) Switzerland on my Pixel 6 Pro running Android 14.

[Settings - System - Date & time] only offers timezone related stuff and setting 12/24h format. In English ->(All regions), Switzerland is not listed; (...Sudan, Sweden, Tanzania..) Might be a Samsung thing.
